# how to make one unique id set when combining two already unique sets

Tags: algorithm

- Unique Id set A has a lot of unique ids within A
- Unique Id set B has a lot of unique ids within B

now I want to combine A and B to form set C,  and make ids still unique.

one of my thoughts:
- prefix A ids with '0'
- prefix B ids with '1'

combine two sets to from C. now I can easily distinguish Ids from its categories, and the combined sets are unique.

can't think up of other flaws at the moment, does it work? any better approaches ?

Comment: I think it works and it's kind of the only way to go...as you must insert some properties / attributes to indicate what is the source of an ID in set C (if it came from A or B).  No matter you add a prefix, add an field / pointer to store to source, you have to do such kind of "encode" thing.  Unless A & B is all positive integers, then you may use naive trick like negative number in C means it came from B etc, I think this is unavoidable

Comment: If you cannot mix unique id from A(B) and C it's ok.